# jquery move content to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 columns, one with the text and one with footnotes and images.
When i load the text with ajax everything will be in column1. I want to move the images to column2.

Atm  i use:

```
$(".b_footnote").appendTo("#column2");
```

Which works but i would like to keep the original y position as well.
Is that possible?

My other attempt was just moving it away:

```
$('.b_footnote').each(function() {
   var xPos = $("#column1").offset().left;
   xPos += 540;
    $(this).offset({'left':xPos});
});
```

The problem with this is that i have a div on the left of column1 which can change in width, and once that does then the footnotes are in the incorrect position.

Here's a jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Hnxdr/

I got it:

---

```
$('.b_footnote').each(function() {
     var y = $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).appendTo("#column2");
    $(this).offset({'top':y});
});
```

Only the result is very ugly, as you can see at the image ("the word 'de' being at the right).
Does someone know how to get the context from the span and past it into a fit or a

?
(That should look better)
[image]

Comment: why not load the images into the side column in the first place from within the ajax callback? would be more economic on performance, as well..

Comment: added a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Hnxdr/

Comment: And i need to finish this by monday so performance or perfect coding is not my goal anymore atm.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on the jsfiddle you provided and this works fine

```
$('.b_footnote').each(function() {
   var xPos = $(this).offset();   

    $(this).appendTo("#column2");

    var col2pos = $("#column2").offset().left;

    $(this).offset({top:xPos.top, left: col2pos});
});
```

change the changeColumnWidth function like this

```
function changeColumnWidth() {
    var w = Math.random() * 200+180;
    $('#menu').css("width", w+"px");
    var col2pos = $("#column2").offset().left;
    $('.b_footnote').each(function() {

        $(this).offset({ left: col2pos});
   });    

}​
```

Comment: There's a button changeColumnWidth, if you press that then the footnotes are in the wrong position. (that's why i'm hoping for a appendTo version).

Comment: Edit the answer and updated the jsfiddle, check and see this works

Comment: things will become more complex in a while. changeColumnWidth is just a test function. Solving things there is no option really. If you our someone else can get the appending done then that would be really help full. (although thanks so far)